# How can I iterate through Excel Worksheets that aren't explicitly named using XlsxWriter?

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlsxwriter, worksheet

I'm a total novice when it comes to programming. I'm trying to write a Python 3 program that will produce an Excel workbook based on the contents of a CSV file. So far, I understand how to create the workbook, and I'm able to dynamically create worksheets based on the contents of the CSV file, but I'm having trouble writing to each individual worksheet.

Note, in the example that follows, I'm providing a static list, but my program dynamically creates a list of names based on the contents of the CSV file: the number of names that will be appended to the list varies from 1 to 60, depending on the assay in question.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:\\Users\\Jabocus\\Desktop\\Workbook.xlsx')
list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

for x in list:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(x)
    worksheet.write("A1", "Hello!")

workbook.close()
```

If I run the program as it appears above, I get a SyntaxError, and IPython points to workbook.close() as the source of the problem.

However, if I exclude the line where I try to write "Hello!" to cell A1 in every worksheet, the program runs as I'd expect: I end up with Workbook.xlsx on my desktop, and it has 4 worksheets named a, b, c, and d.

The for loop seemed like a good choice to me, because my program will need to handle a variety of CSV formats (I'd rather write one program that can process data from every assay at my lab than a program for each assay).

My hope was that by using worksheet.write() in the way that I did, Python would know that I want to write to the worksheet that I just created (i.e. I thought worksheet would act as the name for each worksheet during each iteration of the loop despite explicitly naming each worksheet something new).

It feels like the iteration is the problem here, and I know that it has something to do with how I'm trying to reference each Worksheet in the write() step (because I'm not giving any of the Worksheet objects an explicit name), but I don't know how to proceed. What's a good way that I might approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what is wrong with your code, but I can tell you this:

I copied your code exactly (except for changing the path to be my desktop) and it worked fine.

I believe your issue could be one of three things:

1. You have a buggy/old version of `XlsxWriter`
2. You have a file called `Workbook.xlsx` on your Desktop already that is corrupted or causing some issues (open in another program.)
3. You have some code other than what you posted.

To account for all of these possibilities, I would recommend that you:

1. **Reinstall `XlsxWriter`:**

   In a Command Prompt run `pip uninstall XlsxWriter` followed by `pip install XlsxWriter`
2. **Change the filename of the workbook you are opening:**

   `workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:\\Users\\Jabocus\\Desktop\\Workbook2.xlsx')`
3. **Try running the code that you posted *exactly*, then incrementally add to it until it stops working.**

Comment: Thanks for taking a time to look at this. It's a huge relief that, at the very least, my thought process was good enough.

Comment: @Jacobus So you were able to figure it out?

Comment: No, I actually meant to expand on that initial comment, but when I pressed enter to go to a new line, that posted. For the last 10 minutes I was trying to edit my comment, but the changes didn't take T~T. The short of it is that 3. was correct: my example code isn't the code that I'm trying to fix. It was just supposed to be analogous. I'm going to take your advice and try to build off of my working example code.

Comment: Ok, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like `worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello')` 
instead of `worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')`

Comment: Yeah, I've done it on an XlsxWriter test file that I'm using, but I don't think the coordinate syntax that I'm using is part of the issue.